# how to source STDOUT with csh

Tags: csh

I'm writing code that needs to set environmental variables in both bash and csh.
With bash I can do this to read from stdout:

`source <(init_script args)`

I can't seem to find the equivalent for csh.

I could do this:

`` eval `init_script args` ``

but then I'm worried about the length of the line I'd be generating.

are their other options besides a temporary file?

Comment: I don't think this would work, but did you try `init_script args | source` ? Otherwise I think it's going to be a tmp file. Good luck.

Comment: I did even though I was pretty sure from the man page that it wouldn't work. the syntax is "source NAME" and it means it ... 8- (

Comment: Sorry! Did you try looking for users with high scores on `csh`? Maybe ping them? Offer a bounty? (I had 3-4 yrs of corporate enforced usage and did a lot with csh, but don't recall this issue). Oh, ouch, only 465 watchers. Look at it this way, debugging problems with a tmp file eliminates a whole class of "mysterious" prroblems (-;! Good luck!

Comment: AFAIK there's isn't a good way to do this, other than the temporary file.